# Connect to MongoDB server with Driver 2.0 best practice

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I have VB.net code that connects to a MongoDB. When the database is up and running my code works fine, but when the database is not running I don't get any errors back.

How do I check that the Server is up and running so I can connect to it and do my work? Basically IF the Server is up do work ELSE return a message to user that server is not available.

I look at the documentation about the MongoClient Class but I can't seem to find anything I can use.

MongoClient Class (http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClient.htm)

Below is my code that works to connect to the MongoDB:

```
Public Function DbConnection(ByRef ConnString As String, vDbName As String, vColName As String) As MongoClient

    'default port
    'ConnString = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

    'example DB and Collection
    'vDbName = "blog"
    'vColName = "users"

    'Root Object
    Dim vClient As MongoClient
    vClient = New MongoClient(ConnString)

    Dim vDb As MongoDatabaseBase
    vDb = vClient.GetDatabase(vDbName)

    Dim vCol As IMongoCollection(Of BsonDocument)
    vCol = vDb.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)(vColName)

    Return vClient

End Function
```

Below is additional code where I use InsertOneAsync without creating an error:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If txtName.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter a Name for the Database.")
    Else

        Dim ConnString As String
        ConnString = txtConnStr.Text

        Dim vDbName As String
        vDbName = txtDb.Text

        Dim vColName As String
        vColName = txtColl.Text

        'Root Object
        Dim vClient As MongoClient

        vClient = DbConnection(ConnString, vDbName, vColName)

        Dim vDb As MongoDatabaseBase
        vDb = vClient.GetDatabase(vDbName)

        Dim vCol As IMongoCollection(Of BsonDocument)
        vCol = vDb.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)(vColName)

        Dim vAddUser As BsonDocument
        vAddUser = New BsonDocument

        vAddUser.Add("_Id", txtID.Text)
        vAddUser.Add("Name ", txtName.Text)
        vAddUser.Add("Email", txtEmail.Text)
        vAddUser.Add("City", txtCity.Text)

        rtfDataDisplay.Text = "BsonDocument = " & vAddUser.ToString & ", #" & vAddUser.Count

        Await vCol.InsertOneAsync(vAddUser)

    End If
End Sub
```

Below is the solution I came up with. I am only posting the Try...Catch since I have already posted entire procedures above.

```
        Try

            Dim watch As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch

            watch.Start()

            Dim insertResult As Task = vCol.InsertOneAsync(vAddUser)
            Await insertResult

            watch.Stop()

            MsgBox("Faulted =" & insertResult.IsFaulted.ToString & ", Status = " & insertResult.Status.ToString & ", Watch = " & watch.Elapsed.ToString)

        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.HResult.ToString = "-2146233083" Then

                MsgBox("unable to insert data due to a timeout exception")
            Else
                MsgBox("Unable to insert data = " & ", HResult = " & ex.HResult.ToString & "!" & ex.ToString)
            End If

        End Try
```

Comment: Do you get an error if you perform an action on the collection. For instance, vCol.Count() or vCol.Exists().

Comment: I don't check for errors. The code will run and finish without breaking. You would think it added the document but when I go to the shell and check no document has been added. When I start the shell and run the same insert document code I see the document added fine. That is what made me think to set up a check for the server running so I know the documents are added.

Comment: I am not sure the code that you have in the function above will fail if the server is not running because it never actually has to access the database. If you exercise it with a vCol.Exists() call just before the return statement then it will be forced to check for the server and will fail if no connection is found. You could then capture that exception and act appropriately. Hope I have understood the problem correctly!

Comment: I like what you are saying. I don't get the .Exist() method from my intellisense. I thought the "Await vCol.InsertOneAsync()" I use in another sub would be enough to access the database.

Comment: Or `Await vCol.CountAsync()` if you don't want to insert any data just to test the connection. Think Exists() is now obsolete. If you are able to do the Await InsertOneAsync() without causing an error when the database isn't running it might be worth posting that code as well.

Comment: I added the code to my question if that helps

Comment: Think your problem is around the way you await: http://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-20-net-driver If you get the task object back from InsertOneAsync(), call .Wait() on it and then check the task object is completed or faulted.

Comment: I don't fully understand how to use await. I am new to using Async methods and the MongoDB Driver is full of them. Would you be able to give me a example of how I should call that in VB with Await?

Comment: If you do `Dim insertResult As Task = vCol.InsertOneAsync(vAddUser)` and then `Await insertResult`. You can then check `insertResult.isFaulted` and `insertResult.Status`.

Comment: When I test it I get back Faulted = False, Status = WaitingForActivation. I had the Wait set for 1,000 miliseconds. This is super helpful I will work with it some more and see if I can find a way to use in answering my question. Thanks for the advice. I will keep everyone updated on what works for me. I will be gone all day, gotta run

Answer (score 0):

Since the asynch only returns Task, it doesn't wait until the operation is complete. If you wait after the task and then you will capture the exception and process it accordingly, Here is the sample

Change this 
`Await vCol.InsertOneAsync(vAddUser)`

```
Var insertTask = vCol.InsertOneAsync(vAddUser); insertTask.Wait();
```

and then remove the async keyword from the button_click method signature.

Comment: Thanks for the post XtremeBytes but I am looking for code written in VB.net. @theduck wrote a similar example but he didn't post it as an answer. I did some testing and came up with using a Try...Catch. Basically when the DB isn't running I need to catch the timeout exception to know that nothing was written to the Mongo database. I will add the code to the bottom of my question.